# Function for next and previous button for highliting word in StyledText field

Tags: java, swt

I develope file manager app, so I need to implement in it function to highlight words in text area and go over them through buttons "Next" and "Previous". But I cant find a way how to store right my highlited words in stream.

I tried to write a function below. Added to buttons event handlers.

```
private static int changeTextView(StyledText tv, String target, int selected) {
    if (selected < 0) {
        selected = 0;
    }
    String text = tv.getText().toString();
    int startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0;

    LinkedList<StyleRange> list = new LinkedList<StyleRange>();
    int currentIndex = 0;

    while (true) {
        startIndex = text.indexOf(target, endIndex);
        endIndex = startIndex + target.length();

        boolean isLast = text.indexOf(target, endIndex) < 0;
        if (startIndex < 0)
            break;

        if (currentIndex == selected || isLast && selected > currentIndex) {
            //list.add(setSelection(startSpan, endSpan));
            tv.setSelection(startIndex, endIndex);
            if (isLast && selected > currentIndex) {
                selected = currentIndex;
            }
        } else {
            tv.setSelection(startIndex, endIndex);
        }

        currentIndex++;
        //getHighlightStyle(startSpan, endSpan);
    }
    //tv.styles = (StyleRange[]) list.toArray(new StyleRange[list.size()]);

    if (currentIndex == 0) {
        // text not found
        return -1;
    } else {
        return selected;
    }
}
```

And buttons event handlers will look something like this
 {

```
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            selected++;
            changeTextView(styledText, keyword, selected);
        }
```

function to highlight

```
private static StyleRange getHighlightStyle(int startOffset, int length) {
    StyleRange styleRange = new StyleRange();
    styleRange.start = startOffset;
    styleRange.length = length;
    styleRange.background = shell.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW);
    return styleRange;
}
```

Any help appreciate.